# route codeigniter not load the page

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

my problem is about the route of codeigniter, I'm working with that and for each function i wrote the route. When i put the last route, this one not working and it give me 404 error. I don't know why? maybe i'm doing mistake about the order of route but i think is right.
This is my route:

```
 //MATCH SHARE
// route not working 
    $routes['upload_image/upload_photo'] = "upload_image/upload_photo"; 

//all route working
    //VOTATION//
    $route['auth_social/fblogin'] = "auth_social/fblogin";
    $route['votation/user_plus/(:any)'] = "votation/user_plus";
    $route['votation/user_minum/(:any)'] = "votation/user_minum";



    $route['finish_registration/(:any)/(:any)'] = "auth/activate"; // activate e-mail
    $route['auth'] = "auth"; // index auth
    $route['register'] = "auth/register";
    $route['login'] = "auth/login"; // login
    $route['logout'] = "auth/logout";
    $route['default_controller'] = "auth/register"; // register

    $route['(:any)'] = "profile/user";

    $route['404_override'] = '';
```

htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Try to put the route which is not working befoter 404_override, also try to route it to "profile/user" for example just to see whether the route is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$routes['upload_image/upload_photo/?']    = "upload_image/upload_photo";
$routes['upload_image/upload_photo/(.+)'] = "upload_image/upload_photo/$1";
```

If you need to have extra uri segments, your current one won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is wrong  `$routes` it should be  `$route['upload_image/upload_photo'] = "upload_image/upload_photo";`